# Suggest some beginner projects related to data analytics

Tags: python, excel, visualization, analytics

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I'm relatively new to the field of data analytics and am eager to enhance my skills and build a strong resume. I believe that practical experience is crucial, and I'm looking for some beginner-level data analytics projects to work on. These projects will not only help me solidify my understanding but also add value to my resume.

I have a good grasp of foundational concepts in data analytics, including data cleaning, exploratory data analysis, data visualization, and basic statistical analysis. However, I'm looking to take the next step and gain hands-on experience by working on real-world projects.

Here's what I'm hoping to achieve with these projects:

Apply my knowledge in a practical context.
Gain experience with data collection, preprocessing, and analysis.
Improve my data visualization skills.
Learn how to draw actionable insights from data.
Strengthen my problem-solving abilities.
I'm open to a wide range of project ideas, and I'm willing to work with different datasets and tools. Ideally, these projects should be suitable for someone at the beginner to intermediate level.

If you have any project ideas, suggestions, or resources to share, I would greatly appreciate your input. Additionally, if you could provide guidance on how to get started with a particular project or recommend any specific datasets or tools, that would be extremely valuable.

Answer (score 1):

- Exploratory Data Analysis (EDA) on a Real Dataset
- Geospatial Analysis()
- Dashboard Creation:

  1.Build interactive data dashboards using tools like Tableau, Power BI, or
  Python libraries like Dash or Streamlit.
  2.Create a dashboard for a dataset that interests you, showcasing key
  insights.

To get started with these projects, you'll need to choose a dataset that aligns with your interests and goals. You can find datasets on platforms like Kaggle, GitHub, or data.gov. Python is a popular choice for data analysis, and libraries like Pandas, Matplotlib, Seaborn, and scikit-learn are very useful.